# Older passport lost

Tags: passports, lost-documents

I have lost my older passport. Which countries might ask me for my older passport??? Is it will be OK if I show them a copy of police report??? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you get a new passport? If yes then no one would ask about the old one. If you had some valid visas on the old one then you should contact the relevant embassy for instructions.

Comment: Yap. I've got a newer one. No valid Visa was attached to the older one. Thanks for your help.